# How to fetch two different columns from two different tables and put it into a third table with one to one mapping?

Tags: sql, postgresql, plpgsql, postgresql-9.5

Consider I have two tables parent_table with parent_id column and child_table with child_id column. Now I have to give mapping for the child and parent in another table called mapping_table with parent_id and child_id as columns. How can I do this in postgresql 9.5? The No of records in both tables are huge, So I can't do this manually. Suggest me the best way by which i can do this mapping

Say the records in table are like this:
parent_table:

```
|parent_id|
 1
 2
 3
```

child table:

```
|child_id|
 01
 02
 03
```

The result should be as follows:
mapping table

```
parent_id | child_id
1         | 01
2         | 02
3         | 03
```

Comment: how they are correlated?.. is child_id  a text field equal to parent_id with preceding zero?..

Comment: there is no relation between the tables the id's can be anything

Comment: If there is no relation, then can you do a full join?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a query like the following:

```
INSERT INTO mapping_table (parent_id, child_id)
SELECT t1.parent_id, t2.child_id
FROM (
    SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY parent_id) AS rn,
           parent_id
    FROM parent_table) AS t1
JOIN (
    SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY child_id) AS rn,
           child_id
    FROM child_table) AS t2
ON t1.rn = t2.rn;
```

The query uses `ROW_NUMBER` in order to relate the two tables to each other. This results in a 1-1 mapping.

[**Demo here**](http://rextester.com/ENQO7601)